# VS2008 can't reference a .NET 3.5 assembly built in VS2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I know that VS2008 can't work with .NET 4.0 and that the .NET 4.0 assembly file format has changed from 3.5. However, I would have thought that assemblies built by VS2010 targeting .NET 3.5 or earlier would be compatible with VS2008.

Attempting to reference a VS2010 DLL results in the yellow caution overlay on the icon, and a "This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built.  Please ensure that the project is available and built." dialog pops up when you attempt to open the reference.

The VS2010 assembly is being built as Release/Any CPU - and this is on Windows 7 32-bit. The assembly is not being signed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there were post-build actions occurring which include calling ildasm and ilasm in order to rename methods within the assembly. During this process, obviously something is getting corrupted in the DLL.

When I do not perform the post-build activities, the assembly (that targets .NET 3.5) can be referenced in VS2008 just fine.

Comment: Using the ildasm and ilasm utilities that ship with VS2008 fixed this issue. Specifically, I just ran the Visual Studio 9.0 version of VSVARS32.bat. There might be switches to get VS2010's ildasm and ilasm to be backwards compatible, but I didn't see anything in the ilasm help that was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to think the assembly is created by another project in the solution.  Maybe that was once the case and you removed the project from the solution?  Delete the assembly reference and add it back with the Browse tab.

Comment: This is a third-party assembly that was never built as part of the VS 2008 solution. I built a new version of the DLL in VS 2010 and added it to the VS 2008 solution by deleting the reference and adding it back in via Browse.

Comment: Ah, I apologize for not being clear. I meant to indicate that the issue was not what you suggested. I had been deleting and re-adding the reference quite often while I was tweaking settings when building the DLL. Thank you for your thoughts though.

Comment: I dunno, tell us how to repro this problem.  Pare down the VS2010 built assembly to its core but still exhibits this problem and post it at a file sharing service.